# Prevent Designer from removing Attributes on Control members

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I want to mark certain controls on my Windows Form with Attributes. So I added the Attribute in my `TestAttributes.Designer.cs`:

```
[AmbientValue(true)]
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

But whenever I change the `Modifiers`-property of label1 using the properties-window of the designer, the Designer silently removes my Attribute from the declaration:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

I tried putting the declaration in the `TestAttributes.cs` to not mess with the .Designer.cs file. But when changing the `Modifiers` property the declaration is moved back to  `TestAttributes.Designer.cs` and the Attribute is gone.

How can I prevent the Designer from removing my Attributes?

**EDIT:**
The question should better be: Can I *permanently* move the declaration of a control out of the `*.Designer.cs` file, so I can apply an Attribute there? As I wrote above, it gets moved back in some cases.

Thank you!
richn

Comment: There are a number of problems with this. First off, you aren't supposed to modify the `*.Designer.cs` file because it's regenerated by the designer automatically. That's why it's hidden by default. Secondly, it doesn't make any sense to set the ambient value of a `Label` control to `true`. How can a Label control be `true`? If necessary, inherit from the control and add whatever default properties you want, then use *that* custom control in the designer.

Comment: Yea I know modifying the .Designer.cs file is bad but I thought maybe there is a way to get the declaration of the Label out of there. But I guess what I tried is just as bad ;-). `Label` and `AmbientValue` are only examples in a test application, in my real application it's a custom Attribute.

Comment: You can always move things *out* of the `*.Designer.cs` file into your *own* code files. Then, the designer won't modify them. This is the same thing you do when you want to add code to the default `Dispose` method. If you know it's bad/doesn't work, it's unclear why you're doing it anyway.

Comment: I did try moving the declaration out of the `*.Designer.cs` and to my own code file. But it is moved back to `*.Designer.cs` and my Attribute is lost when I change the `Modifiers` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep designer support, I recommend using an external class library.

```
    namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.AmbientValue(true)]
        public class TestClass : System.Windows.Forms.Label
        {
        }
    }
```

You can compile something like this to a class library, and then import it to visual studio. If you don't know how to do that, follow the instructions below.

1. Right click the toolbox
2. Click "Choose Items"
3. Wait. Do not make the mistake of terminating visual studio now.
4. Select Browse.
5. Select your dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I normally don't like people who give the "don't do it" answer, but don't do it.

Changing the designer class is dangerous, and can almost always lead to unexpected consequences.  The designer code is reserved for the compiler, and it should always look like the compiler expects it to look.

If you really wanted attributes in what would otherwise be your designer code, you should instead make an empty application, and do the forms code yourself.  You shouldn't be trying to modify designer code anyway, if you don't understand how to do it from scratch

If that seems like a lot of work, you can always try to use the designer as a model, and then copy that over to a new, non-windows forms project.

Answer (score 0):

Untill recently i was lead to believe that designer was just part of the code and it was not to be touched.  I was wrong. Turns out you can rip the entire thing out and then compiler will throw an error at you.  Okay, that's fine, just define your own stuff, completely thus eliminating the necessity for a designer.  here is how.  Say you have a tag

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
```

and you want to make it invisible on the back side without any designer.cs file present (we deleted it).  First reference it along with other declarations (i.e. outside of page_load, somewhere on the outside)

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1;
```

Remember however, you MUST reference EVERYTHING that you use on the front side that has a runat="server" tag.  So say you have a page with only a runat="server" label, on the back we reference to it as

```
namespace yournamespace.something
{
    public class yourpagetitle: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgLogo;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox tbDate;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label yourLabelName;
```

Notice I added image and a textbox as additional examples.  And huzza! You have thus completely eliminated the need for designer.cs file.  Oh, and do notice, designer.cs file is nothing more than what we just did above, but it does it for you automatically. ...most of the time... When it fails, time to handle things your own way.  I'm sure if you reformat your computer, reinstall everything, etc etc etc things will work again, no doubt.  This is just a legitimate work around for those who do not have time to babysit and troubleshoot every little hick-up Microsoft does.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid using the `*.designer.cs` file **if you avoid using the designer**. That's all the file is for, in fact. It's a private file automatically generated by the designer, implemented using partial classes to hide it from the user for convenience purposes. If you don't use the designer, then you don't have to use the designer file. But if you *do* modify the designer file, it will get re-written whenever you work in the designer again. There's nothing broken about the system here.